# GRPC Error when calling Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to call the GA4 analytics api using the API quickstart guilde, but I'm getting a GRPC error when calling:

Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1686669889.017000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3218,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1686669889.017000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"......\src\core\lib\transport\error_utils.cc","file_line":165,"grpc_status":14}]}")'

Any advice?

This is the sample code I am using:

````
BetaAnalyticsDataClient client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient.Create();

            // Initialize request argument(s)
            //RunReportRequest request = new RunReportRequest
            //{
            //    Property = "properties/" + propertyId,
            //    Dimensions = { new Dimension { Name = "eventName" }, },
            //    //Metrics = { new Metric { Name = "eventCount" }, },
            //    DateRanges = { new DateRange { StartDate = "2023-03-31", EndDate = "today" }, },
            //};

            RunReportRequest request = new RunReportRequest
            {
                Property = "properties/" + propertyId,
                Dimensions = { new Dimension { Name = "city" }, },
                Metrics = { new Metric { Name = "activeUsers" }, },
                DateRanges = { new DateRange { StartDate = "2020-03-31", EndDate = "today" }, },
            };
            try
            {
                // Make the request
                var response = client.RunReport(request);

                Console.WriteLine("Report result:");
                foreach (Row row in response.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row.DimensionValues[0].Value, row.MetricValues[0].Value);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                throw;
            }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a network issue which should be solved by using correct protocol. You can try to set **GrpcAdapter** property of the **builder** when creating the client?

```
var client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClientBuilder
{
    GrpcAdapter = RestGrpcAdapter.Default
}.Build();
```

You can find more details in official docs: https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta/latest/#using-the-rest-http11-transport

Comment: Thank you so much... That has seemed to correct the issue I have been facing.